# Setting round background for text of button in Android

Tags: android, button, layout, text, background

I have a button in my app in which I am setting the background of it using :
setBackground(Drawable background)

Then I am using setText(CharSequence,TextView.BufferType) to display text on it at the bottom.

Now the question is I am trying to put a rounded background on just the text. I am looking at the android documentation for button but am unable to find any helpful function to put a background for just the text of a button.

To be more clear:
[image]

I am trying to get the yellow part. Any help/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: To be clear the red shape is the button itself. And the yellow shape is the background I want around the text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XML` as the custom background for your button to give it a style as needed like this for example

`round_button_file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#6F2500"/>
<stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#fff" />
```

and then set the background for your button as that XML file

`code for button`

```
<Button
android:layout_width="30sp"
android:layout_height="30sp"
android:background="@drawable/round_button_file"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="Text"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried your solution and it fills the entire button. I just want the shape/background around the text of a button. And a different background for the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

oval_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFF00"/>

</shape>
```

oval_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"

    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/oval_background"
    android:text="TEXT"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I think it could help a lot here. Instead of using a drawable, try instead to extend the button and draw the oval on the canvas.

Here goes:

```
public class YourButton extends Button {

    //declare needed variables
    private Context context;
    private Paint ovalPaint;

    public YourButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        ovalPaint = new Paint();
        ovalPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        ovalPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        ovalPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.YOUR_RED_COLOR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(getOval(canvas), ovalPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas); //important
    }

    private RectF getOval(Canvas canvas) {
        int offset = (int)(canvas.getWidth() * .05);
        return new RectF(0 + offset, 0 + offset, canvas.getWidth() - offset, canvas.getHeight() -           offset);
    }
}
```

And set your xml file as follows:

```
<YourButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```